# how to check this codeigniter php function working or not that function using in ajax url

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

my script code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function changebox(curval,datashow){
    alert(curval);
    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    data:"del="+curval,
    url:"<?php echo site_url('grocery/add_to_show');?>",
    success: function(html){
        $('#'+datashow).html(html);
    }
});
}
</script>
```

the url contain php function

```
url:"<?php echo site_url('grocery/add_to_show');?>",
```

then how to i confirm this PHP function properly working without returning any error

please give a way to solve this problem

Comment: If you view the page source, you can see what is returning that php function. And to see the ajax requests, use the developer tools available in almost any browser.

Comment: you can echo the query u r performing in php function when ajax calls or alert the ajax responce to see the result

Comment: you can check your browser console and network to check url is correct or not and what response you get from ajax request

Comment: ya i checked script returning without error

Comment: You can check it within browsers network if it shows `ststus 200` then every thing is working fine..

Answer (score 0):

Use alert that php code in javascript then you can easily know about what value it is returning.

Comment: you can say this in comment .. this is not answer it is only suggesion

Answer (score 0):

make sure your firebug console tab (or chrome console) is opened. You will see all info if any error occurred.

Comment: ya i checked script perfectly working without returning any error